# how to display all the reviews for the particular product?

Tags: python, django

With the below code i am adding reviews for some particular product in the database and it is doing good but the problem is while displaying the reviews for the selected product.I get confused how can i display the all reviews of some product and which review done by which user at what time?

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    review = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review
```

views.py

```
def detail(request,pk):
    product = College.objects.get(pk=pk)

    form = ReviewForm()
    return render(request,'products/detail.html',{'product':product,'form':form})

 @login_required(login_url='products:signin')
 def review(request,pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
            review.user = request.user
            review.save()
            messages.success(request, "Review saved")
            return redirect('products:detail',pk)
        else:
            messages.error(request,'error in form')
    return redirect('products:detail', pk)
```

detail.html

```
<h3>All reviews(total.no. of reviews?)</h3>
# Here i want to display all reviews and which is done by which user and at what time



         <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-6">
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'products:review' product.pk %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
            {% form.as_p %}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            </form>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this using [**`reverse relation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
<h3>All reviews {{ product.review_set.count }}</h3>
{% for review in product.review_set.all %}
    {{ review.review }}
    {{ review.date }}
{% endfor %}
```